# Getting ump.InvalidFormat at relaychain when sending XCM message

Tags: polkadot, parachain, xcm, substrate-parachain-template

I am getting ump.InvalidFormat when I sending a XCM / UMP from local a local parachain setup to relay chain to. the message instruction is[1][withdraw, buydeposit, deposit] on the relaychain
I am using the substrate-parahchain-template and polkadot.git as relay chain and zomebiet net to start a local chain in order to test sending anc XCM. I am following the example  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBCMV.png) to create and send the xcm message. I have attached images of the zombienet config, xcm message and xcm events are the relaychain.

---

### UPDATE

I have set the safXcmVersion of both the relay chain and the parachain to v2 however I still get thesame error. Looking the the polkadotXcm.sent event emitted by the parachain (image attached), I can see that it sends the xcm message using v3 even though the safeXcmVersion on both chains is set to v2

[image]
[[image]][image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you been able to work it around or fix somehow? @Neo

Answer (score 1):

Try to `WithdrawAsset(0, Here)` rather than `(1, Here)`. `(0,Here)` is the native token in Relaychain, and relaychain cannot handle other tokens.

--- Update

I noticed that the relay chain you are using is v0.9.38, the parachain is v0.9.37, **the update of v0.9.38 includes XCM v3, and the compatibility code is not included in v0.9.37**, so I suggest you use compatibility Relay chain and parachain version. For example, v0.9.37 relay and v0.9.37 parachain. Or v0.9.38 relay and v0.9.38 parachain.

Comment: I have updated and tried WithdrawAsset(0, Here) but still thesame error. I have updated the same images im the question above and added the relay chain account balances image

Comment: @Neo Check the update.

Comment: I have updated both the relay chain and parachain templates to use v0.9.42 but still getting same error. i have updated the zomebienet config image in the question

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the outdated Rococo Local Relay Chain chain-spec that is used to run the validator nodes.

You should either download the latest spec from [here](https://docs.substrate.io/assets/tutorials/relay-chain-specs/raw-local-chainspec.json) and launch the relay chain from scratch or upgrade the runtime up to version `9400` at least to make sure it supports XCM V3 messaging.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is that `xcmPallet.safeStorageVersion` is set to a higher number (ex. 3) than the xcm version you are sending (ex. 2).

You could try adjusting this storage at genesis or call the extrinsic `xcmPallet.forceDefaultXcmVersion` on Relaychain using sudo

Comment: I have set the safXcmVersion of both the relay chain and the parachain to v2 however I still get thesame error. Looking the the polkadotXcm.sent event emitted by the parachain (image attached to question ), I can see that it sends the xcm message using v3 even though the safeXcmVersion on both chains is set to v2

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to set xcm logs to trace

-lxcm=trace

Also please try setting the xcm version of the location. Your logs might indicate that the location (0, parachain(paraID) is unknown